# Prevent DbContext from being disposed until async task completes

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asynchronous, dbcontext

I have a C# core Web API Controller (implementation of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase) that has API method A and API method B.  A is asynchronous and fires and forgets an async worker thread.  B is synchronous.

Both A (and its worker thread) & B read and write from the same database using entity framework.  But the problem I'm having is the DBContext object is disposed before A's worker thread completes.

I'm aware of the principle of the owner of the disposable object should both create and dispose it.  So I considered wrapping A's DBContext in a Repository class that is not disposable, but that seems to violate the analyzer rule: "CA1001: Types that own disposable fields should be disposable" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1001  But if I make the Repository object disposable, Dotnet Core disposes of it when A returns (but before its worker thread completes).

I also considered making the Repository a singleton, but that violates the principle that DbContext objects should be short lived.

Appreciate any suggestions you may have!

Comment: would using a hosted service be an option? The hosted service can then have it's own DbContext instance?

Comment: @MaartenDev that's a helpful suggestion but from what I'm reading, hosted services run for the lifetime of the server, and apparently DbContext objects are supposed to be short lived.  Of course I could have a hosted service that's responsible for kicking off the worker threads, but then I think that puts me back at square one.  Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A is asynchronous and fires and forgets an async worker thread.

Then the worker thread *must not* use the Scoped DbContext managed by Dependency Injection.  Instead it should create the DbContext instance in a `using` block and manage its lifetime explicitly in code.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft but as I mentioned, VS then insists I mark the worker as disposable, in which case the worker itself gets disposed when method A returns (before the worker has finished its work).

Comment: I was suggesting that the DbContext should be a local variable declared in a `using` block, not a member of some other Disposable type.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Ok that makes sense to have the DbContext in a using block, but given that the worker thread uses it in multiple methods, shouldn't it be instantiated once in the constructor and used as a class-level variable?  And if so, doesn't that put me right back at the start, with the same analyzer objection?

Comment: You can create/destroy multiple times, or create in an outer method and pass it into other methods.

Answer (score 1):

In StartUp.cs, instead of adding the dbContext with AddDbContext, try using **AddDbContextPool**